# How do I use the request header for the .Net WebClient FileDownloadAsync method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I've got a .Net WebApi service. For additional security, I have recently added an api_key to the header. The controller pulls the api-key from the request header and validates authorization.

We have the ability also download files asynchronously using the .Net WebClient.
I would like to be able to use an api-key and use it for verification for the download request. We are using DownloadFileAsync() because it gives DownloadProgressChanged() and DownloadFileCompleted() callbacks.

What do I need to do on the Controller side to do this?

**Here is a sample controller method using the api key:**

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage SomeMethod(string param)
{
    var request = Request;
    if (request.Headers.Contains("api_key"))
    {
        string sValue = request.Headers.GetValues("api_key").First();
        if (IsValidApiKey(sValue))
        {
            // Return Unauthorized
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is a sample code snippet calling the controller:**

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    var sParam = "Foo";
    request.RequestUri = new Uri($"{BaseUrl}SomeMethod?param={sParam}");
    request.Method = HttpMethod.Put;
    request.Headers.Add("api_key", "SomeKeyValue");

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var responseTask = client.SendAsync(request);
    responseTask.Wait();
}
```

**Here is the current code snippet for downloading a file:**

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("api_key", "SomeKeyValue");
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += client_DownloadProgressChanged;
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += client_DownloadFileCompleted;
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), filename);
}
```

How do I enforce verification using the api-key contained in the header on the controller?

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up doing an HttpGet and returning a stream.
It would still be nice to know how to access header values/settings on DownloadFileAsync() call.